# Reputation should also be used to downvote

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, questions, down-votes

Recently, there have been several low quality questions, with respect to the topics of this website. For example

- <s>https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/11951/2444</s> (deleted)
- <s>https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/11950/2444</s> (deleted)
- [How do I choose the search algorithm for a particular task?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/11956/2444)
- <s>https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/11938/2444</s> (deleted)

The reputation points should also be used to downvote the posts that deserve to be down-voted (like the mentioned ones), where the asker (or answerer) has put very little (or no) effort in writing an understandable post or has not performed some research before asking, so that to discourage them to do it again next time. It surprises me that these questions do not have more downvotes, which should be the first and fastest visual measure of the quality of the post.

Why is this community too tolerant or often not compliant with the Stack Exchange "standards" (of "good" posts)?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I don't mind the softball questions that could have been answered with a Google search because I feel SE:AI can add context to a Wikipedia entry, and I think we should be the #2 result for that stuff, behind Wikipedia but certainly ahead of Quora.  (Drives traffic to our site and potentially expands our user base.)

Regarding the other stuff, I think we need more voting in general, both up and down!